# Why is the Property Grid not showing the correct color?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a property grid and whenever I click on a rectangle on a panel, it shows the properties of the rectangle. All the properties are correct except for color, which always stays as default (white). I was wondering if there's a way for the property grid to show the rectangle's color.

Here's a screenshot of how it currently looks: 
[image: example screenshot]

Here's how I'm creating a rectangle:
This is from my rectangle class

```
internal class rectangle : Shape
{
        public int length { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }

        Random rand = new Random();
        Rectangle newRectangle;

        public override Rectangle GetRectangle()
        {
            return this.newRectangle;
        }

        private Color randomColor()
        {
            int r = rand.Next(0, 256); // Random number between 0 - 255
            int g = rand.Next(0, 256);
            int b = rand.Next(0, 256);

            Color color = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
            return color;
        }

        private Rectangle makeRectangle(int startx, int starty, int width, int length)
        {
            newRectangle = new Rectangle(startx, starty, width, length);
            return newRectangle;
        }

        public override void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(randomColor()))
            {
                g.FillRectangle(brush, makeRectangle(startx, starty, width, length));
            }
        }
}
```

And the rectangle class is derived from Shape:

```
internal abstract class Shape
    {
        public Color color { get; set; }
        public int thickness { get; set; }
        public int startx { get; set; }
        public int starty { get; set; }

        public abstract Rectangle GetRectangle();   
        public virtual void Draw(Graphics g)
        {
        }
    }
```

And in the main form, I'm drawing the rectangle:

```
// Rectangle 1 
List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
rectangle rectangle = new rectangle();
rectangle.startx = 100;
rectangle.starty = 200;
rectangle.width = 200;
rectangle.length = 100;
shapes.Add(rectangle);

rectangle.Draw(g);
```

Here's the MouseClick event to show the properties:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
            var currentPoints = e.Location;
            Boolean isRectangle = false;
            foreach (Shape shape in shapes)
            {
                if (shape.GetRectangle().Contains(currentPoints))
                {
                    isRectangle = true;
                    propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = shape;
                    objectType = shape.GetType();
                }
            }

            if (isRectangle)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("This is a " + objectType);
                propertyGrid1.Show();

            }
}
```

As per the provided code, I'm creating a SolidBrush with random rgb colors. So I was hoping the property grid to show the correct color. Thanks!

Comment: Your property grid shows properties that are not properties of the standard `System.Drawing.Rectangle`. Where is the definition of the `Rectangle` and `Shape` classes you are using and what and how do you assign to the property grid?

Comment: You need to show the properties. Right now the only issue is that you draw a random color which will obviously not show on the property grid as it's not set in any properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a random color to create a brush in the `Draw` method, but you are not assigning this color to any property of the object you are displaying in the property grid.

You should assign this random color to the `Shape` or `rectangle` object you are displaying in the property grid.

```
rectangle rectangle = new rectangle();
rectangle.color = randomColor(); // <========================
rectangle.startx = 100;
rectangle.starty = 200;
rectangle.width = 200;
rectangle.length = 100;
```

In the `Draw` method you should then use this color

```
using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(this.color))
{
    g.FillRectangle(brush, makeRectangle(startx, starty, width, length));
}
```